# Boolean variable returns as string from javascript function

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when I'm returning, what I think is, a boolean variable from a javascript function, it is detected in the calling function as a string, but if I return a boolean literal, the calling function detects it as a boolean?

So, for example:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#result').text(typeof validate());
    $('#result2').text(typeof validate2());
});

function validate(){
    status = true;
    status = false;
    return status;
}
    
function validate2(){
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

Comment: See also [Simple Javascript array initialization not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3082475/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't declare the `status` status variable.

Therefore, the global one ([`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status)) is overwritten.

However, the [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#window) defines that property as a DOMString:

```
interface Window : EventTarget {
  attribute DOMString status;
};
```

Therefore, it has a setter (either exposed or internal) which stores the stringified value.

To fix it, just declare your local variable using the [`var` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2).

Comment: I don't find the setter part of your explanation, do you have a link to it ?

Comment: @Nobe4 On Firefox you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'status').set`. Chrome doesn't expose the setter, but the value is still stringified before being stored, as specified in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#result').text(typeof validate());
    $('#result2').text(typeof validate2());
});

function validate(){
    var status = true;
    status = false;
    return status;
}
    
function validate2(){
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

**EDIT:** I was building the answer and something go wrong, anyway, the reason is explained well by @Oriol: The global window.status variable is the one which has the string value type.

Comment: You should explain why using a local variable makes a difference for this.

Comment: I found that there is a gobal variable named `status`. Maybe that is related... `> typeof window.status ` => `string`

Comment: @Barmar really sorry, something go wrong while building the answer, do you think I should delete this answer to leave the Oriol answer?

Comment: Since his answer doesn't include the corrected code, your answer is also helpful.