# boolean swapping in babel not working

Tags: javascript, boolean, babeljs

just wondering why this boolean isn't changing each time I call the function in Codepen with babel.

```
let status = true;

let statusChange = () => {
  status = !status;
  return `new status: ${status}`;
}

console.log(statusChange());
console.log(statusChange());
console.log(statusChange());
console.log(statusChange());
console.log(statusChange());
```

You should see the console logs alternate between true and false.  Am I going insane here..?

Comment: It works if you chose another name than `status`...

Comment: lol thank you, so the 1 word I choose has now wasted about 1 hour of my life.  I will never use that word again :-P  How do I close this as complete..? Do you now put this in the Answer area..? So this can be completed? Cheers

Comment: If you do typeof status before it is even set, it returns "string" very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel transforms your code into this:

```
var status = true;

var statusChange = function statusChange() {
  status = !status;
  return "new status: " + status;
};

console.log(statusChange());
console.log(statusChange());
console.log(statusChange());
console.log(statusChange());
console.log(statusChange());
```

As you can see, `let status = true` has been changed into `var status = true`. Unfortunately, there is a big difference between `let` and `var` which Babel didn't consider here:

> At the top level of programs and functions, let, unlike var, does not
>   create a property on the global object.
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules)

Unfortunately, there is already a property `status` on the global object (i.e. `window.status`). Thus, with `var`, you run into this issue described here: [Boolean variable returns as string from javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685364/boolean-variable-returns-as-string-from-javascript-function)

Comment: I think this overrides the other question as a more complete answer now :-)

Comment: @Pocketninja I have full sympathies for any developer who goes crazy over this ;) - Actually, I wonder if this is a bug within babel or rather codepen...