# Why is my variable "status" showing up deprecated in my code?

Tags: javascript

Why is my variable `status` showing up deprecated in my code? How do you fix this? Sorry, I'm fairly knew to JavaScript.

```js
var age = prompt("what is your age?");

if (age >= 18 && age <= 35) {
  status = "target demo";
  console.log(status);
} else {
  status = "not my audience";
  console.log(status);
}
```

Comment: Because there used to be a global predefined variable called status which will soon be removed. Don't worry about it; if you're annoyed change the variable name.

Comment: You never actually show us what `status` is, only how you are using it. That doesn't give anyone enough information on why it would be marked deprecated.

Comment: `window.status` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

Comment: What do you mean by "deprecated"? Can you share the full and exact error message you are facing? When I run the code, I don't see any such error

Comment: Related: [Boolean condition is always false when using `status == true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479819/boolean-condition-is-always-false-when-using-status-true/62479880#62479880) and [Can't populate array called `status`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082475/cant-populate-array-called-status). Avoid `var`!

Comment: If you properly declared your variables it would not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because you are trying to use the `status` variable without defining it, as **@epascarello**
pointed out; If you use the `status` variable without defining it, you are overwriting the `Window.status`<sup>[1]</sup> property, but you do not get the warning that the `status` variable is not defined.

As **@maksymiuk** stated, if you use the `status` variable by defining it yourself, you will write it to the `status` variable that you do not recognize, not the `Window.status` property.

```js
var age = prompt("what is your age?");
let status;

if (age >= 18 && age <= 35) {
  status= "target demo";
  console.log(status);
} else {
  status= "not my audience";
  console.log(status);
}
```

---

<sup>1 - [Window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)</sup>

Comment: status should be fine if the OP actually declared it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar Status isn’t in the list?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Listed as the name of HTML and Window objects and properties; [Windows - Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

Comment: *Reserved words* are part of the lexical grammar of ECMAScript; `status` is a now obsolete property of the Window object which is globally accessible in browsers, but it is not a reserved word per say; W3School is oversimplifying. You CAN declare a variable called `status`, just not in the global scope.

Comment: @Domino `epascarello` has already told you why. This issue arises because the OP did not define the status variable; because it does not warn that the variable is not defined, but because it can use the variable, it looks for the problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Sercan there is no need to rename status once it is declared with a `let`

Comment: @maksymiuk you are right.

Comment: @Sercan I am aware of the reason why OP's code causes an error, but *reserved word* has a special meaning in JS, and `status` isn't one since you indeed can declare a variable with this name.